# Using text and numbers in a vector image using Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, vector, mac

I'm not here to debate if which program is better, I have only one, since Inkscape no longer works on OS X without some tweaking. I am using Photoshop.

I have a vector image I have been working on, it's simple, but it's mine.  Before I start to add more time to this project, I need to ask, is there a way to make letters and numbers into "shapes" using Photoshop? Just like how you can do using Photoshop with the other drawing tools?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right click on the text layer, use ***Convert to Shape***

[image: Convert text to shape]

You will then be able to modify the text as if it were a vector shape

[image: Text as a vector shape]

You should duplicate and hide your text layer before doing this, as it is a destructive action (can't convert the shape back into text!)